# When writing a movie or a tv show, how do you insure that the transitions between scenes don't feel abrupt and random?

Tags: creative-writing, screenwriting

When writing a movie or a tv show, how do you insure that the transitions between scenes don't feel abrupt and random?

I was watching Star Wars and I thought the movie didn't flow very well from scene to scene and the transitions were random and didn't flow naturally like in most film, but I don't know if this is due to terrible narration where we constantly change scene and where the order doesn't matter a bit, or the use of wipe transitions that give this effect.

How do you make sure that your story flows well? Is there anything you should watch out for, or it doesn't matter and you can glue any scene with another without any issue?

Comment: Please, ensure not insure - they mean different things. Pet hate!

Answer (score 3):

Take the [advice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9jEg9uiLOU) of Matt Stone and Trey Parker (writers of South Park):

Make a list of your scenes.

Make sure you can put a "but" or "therefore" between each scene. Avoid "and then".

I.e. chain the scenes together as causes and effects or complications. Do not just make a list of random events.

Another way to say this is that if your manuscript reads like a project leader's wet dream for a perfect project (i.e. successful scene after successful scene) you're at a very high risk of being boring.

Ending each scene in a setback is one way to make the character's journey through your story more of a crooked one than a straight line.

Connecting every scene with "but" or "therefore" can be hard in the very beginning of some stories where several threads are introduced (e.g. two threads developed in every other scene) and then converge later, perhaps in the first plot point, the midpoint, or even later.

After a certain point though, you should try to connect things in a causational manner.

A half-decent solution would at least make sure each thread's scenes are connected with "but" or "therefore", but a superb story will have this connection between most, if not all, scenes.

Totally disconnected threads can very well raise questions about why they are happening in the same novel, why they weren't made into an anthology, etc. I'd recommend making sure the threads converge at the latest in the climax.

And yes, as you've already suspected; far from all movies and scripts do this and they are worse off for it, so while this is great advice, it doesn't always happen.

Comment: A perfect answer that solved why my chapters are poorly connected. Thanks @Erk.